# Программа должна выдавать значение, по ключу введеному пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть программа

```py
qa = {"Как дела" : "Хорошо", "Что делаешь?": "Программирую"}

while True:
    user_say = input("Введи что-нибудь: ")
    if user_say == [""]:
        print("")
        break
```

Её нужно доработать, чтобы программа вытягивала значение по ключу, введённому пользователем

Прошу хотя бы навести на правильное решение, заранее спасибо!

Comment: У словаря (т. е. у `qa`) есть метод [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), который позволяет получить значение по ключу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словарь вопрос-ответ у Вас уже есть просто добавьте if с print с ответом и проверкой на его наличие.

```
qa = {"Как дела" : "Хорошо", "Что делаешь?": "Программирую"}

while True:
    user_say = input("Введи что-нибудь: ")
    if not user_say:
        print("Пока")
        break
    if qa.get(user_say):
            print(qa[user_say])
```